# How to handle themes for components built using pattern-lab?

Tags: themes, patternlab.io

We have used pattern-lab to build some set of components following atomic design principles. We have a requirement now to theme these components for different websites. Fonts, colors would vary across each site. I would like to understand what would be the best approach to handle themes for components built using pattern lab?

Looking for a design solution on how to organize specific styles related to a theme of site in pattern-lab or is there any standard way to follow to easily achieve this flexibility of switching between themes for various components?